# Custom object page “not supported on mobile device” in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am using a link in a workflow email to a custom object in SFDC1
Salesforce1 Link:

```
`com.salesforce.salesforce1://entity/view?entityId={!Tradeshow__c.Link}`
```

I'm getting a error

> The page you are trying to access is not supported on mobile devices

However I can search for the account and access the Tradeshow in the account in SFDC1.
Is there away to make the link also work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this is not a cool answer, but, as per this question I made a few days ago; have you tried turning it off and on again?!

[Standard object page "not supported on mobile device" in Salesforce1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33952/standard-object-page-not-supported-on-mobile-device-in-salesforce1)

The long and short is that you need to properly close SF1 on your mobile device (on most devices by accessing the application manager and swiping it out of sight).

The reason for this seems to be a local caching/setup problem in the app if you are trying to access new pages created synchronously with the Salesforce1 app being open and authenticated on your "test" device.

Comment: Hi there, yes I have tried turning it off and on and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Bummer. Is this the standard view page for this object? Or do you have a Visualforce override for it perhaps? If so that needs to have the magic 'available for mobile' box checked?

Comment: Standard, no Visualforce.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass a link in, but the object Id. Notice the parameter is named `entityId`. Simply change your merged value to `{!Tradeshow__c.Id}`