# Sforce.one.navigateURL

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

I want to create contact using this way but I am getting error "The page you are trying to access is not supported on mobile device"

```
  <apex:page >

<script>
    function MyApp(sfone) {
        this.createAccount = function() {
            sfone.navigateToURL("/001/e");
        };
    } 

    var app30 = null;

    // Initialize app: get versioned API, wire up clicks
    sforce.one.getVersion("30.0", function(sfoneV30) {
        // Create app object with versioned sforce.one
        app30 = new MyApp(sfoneV30);

        // Wire up button event
        var btn = document.getElementById("btnCreateAcct");
        btn.onclick = btnCreateAccount;
    });

    // Events handling functions
    // Can't be fired until app is defined
    function btnCreateAccount() {
        app30.createAccount();
    }
</script>
<input type="button" value="Create Account" onclick="btnCreateAccount()" id="btnCreateAcct"/>
</apex:page>
```

, still getting error I am using following code in vf page
http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/de-de/pages/release-notes/rn_vf_sforce_one_versioning.htm

Comment: Similar to this thread - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33952/standard-object-page-not-supported-on-mobile-device-in-salesforce1

Comment: Mark, its similar thread but solution is not similar